# Getting Error in example Project for hyperledger sawtooth

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I want to start this project https://github.com/hyperledger/education-sawtooth-simple-supply
My environment is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS , docker-compose version 1.17.1, Docker version 20.10.17, when i follow the instruction it pulls the container but in the end it stops with the error

```
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
ERROR: Service 'simple-supply-shell' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update  && apt-get install -y -q curl gnupg  && curl -sSL 'http://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x8AA7AF1F1091A5FD' | apt-key add -   && echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/chime/stable bionic universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list  && apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Your quick assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was that i changed the network option to Bridge Adapter in a virtual machine and it got worked im answering this because i have dont this if someone has resolved other way then post an answer here.